# Pass hash to subroutine comes to error in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, pass-by-reference, subroutine

My code as below,

```
my %srvs = (
    serv_1 => {
         agents => 'agent_path',
         ...
         ...
    },
    serv_2 => {
         <same like above>
    },
    serv_3 => {
          ...
    ........
    ........
    serv_8 => {
            ...
    },
);

        switch ("$option") {
                case 1  { print "Option 1 selected. \n"; &main; }
                case 2  { print "Option 2 selected. \n"; stop(\%srvs); }
                case 3  { print "Option 3 selected. \n"; start(\%srvs); }
                else    { print "Option are not valid. \n"; exit 0; }
        }

sub stop {
        my $servs = @_;

        foreach my $s_name (sort keys %{$servs}) {
                print "$s_name \n";             

                my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("<user_id>\@$s_name", timeout=>30);
                $ssh->error and die "Unable to connect $s_name  --->  " . $ssh->error and print "\n";

                $ssh->pipe_in("perl /<path>/<script_name>.pl stop all") or die "Unable to run command.\n";
        }

}
```

What I try to do is get a server name which is the keys of %srvs, which is (serv_1, serv2, etc.)

When I run the code, I received below error,

> Can't use string ("1") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at
>   .pl line 260, <> line 1.

I also try different method which is call as array from the case control statement,

```
----
----
case 2  { print "Option 2 selected. \n"; my @s = sort keys %srvs; stop("@s"); }
---
---
sub stop {

        my @servs = @_;

        foreach my $s_name (@serv) {
                print "$s_name \n";             

                my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new("<id_server>\@$s_name", timeout=>30);
                $ssh->error and die "Unable to connect $s_name  --->  " . $ssh->error and print "\n";

                $ssh->pipe_in("<path_name> <script_name>.pl stop all") or die "Unable to run command.\n";
        }
}
```

This code can be process, however it list all the server name (which is all the keys of %srvs) in single flat line, I cannot divide the list using foreach.

Need assist since quite confuse with the passing method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assignment is in the scalar context in your `sub stop` on the line

```
my $servs = @_;
```

so `$servs` receives the number of elements of `@_`, that is `1` in your code.  Then the attempt to dereference that `1` with `%{$servs}` draws the error.

Change it to `my ($servs) = @_;` where the `()` results in the list context for `=` <sup>∗</sup>

A few comments.

- The hash with servers is likely to be used mostly via its reference.  Then why not use a hashref, `my $serv = { ... }`
- There is never a reason to quote a scalar, like `"$option"`; just `switch($option)`
- The `&` in front of a sub is quite special; you mostly likely need `main()` instead of `&main`
- Second code sample has `stop("@s");`, whereby `@s` is interpolated inside `""`. So the sub receives a single string: array elements with spaces between them.  You need `stop(@s)`

You seem to be using [Switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/Switch.html) module. It is a rather non-trivial source filter; surely there are other ways to do what you need. The [feature switch](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#The-%27switch%27-feature) is experimental, too.  See [Switch Statements in perlsyn](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Switch-Statements)

---

<sup>∗</sup>   The `my @args = @_;` serves the same purpose of course. Then process `@args` suitably.

A commonly seen way to retrieve the first argument is also

```
sub fun {
    my $first_arg = shift;  # same as: shift @_;
    ...
}
```

The [shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) removes an element from the front of its argument (array), and returns it; by default it acts on `@_` which you thus don't have to write.

This is often seen in object-oriented code, to get the object off of `@_` so that `@_` can then be worked with more easily. But it is also often used when `@_` has a single argument, for convenience.

Comment: Thanks, I already mark your answer as "Accepted Answer", just one question, does this solution also apply in the second code which I pass an array to the sub?

This is because I plan to make another case which point to one server only which I no need to list all the keys of %srvs.. but I plan to use the same subroutine stop to pass the one server name

Comment: @MrAZ Ah, I didn't notice the other one.  In that, the problem is with `"@s"`, that the array us under quotes -- it gets evaluated into a string and your sub receives that one string (all elements separated by spaces)! In that case you'd want `stop(@s)`.  Thank you for the attribution.  Let me know if more questions pop up

Comment: @MrAZ  I added a bit to the answer: A comment on the second code segment and a note on other ways to get arguments from `@_`. Just so you know