# can't print array reference perl

Tags: arrays, perl, pass-by-reference

I printed out the array within the first function and it is valid. I can't print it out in the second function.

Error message: Can't use string ("1") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at ConvertToVformat.pl line 24.

```
my $dir = cwd();
my $source_files = DetermineSourceFiles();
DetermineFileInfo($source_files);

sub DetermineSourceFiles {
    my @source_files;
    opendir my $dh, $dir or die "Cant open $dir: $!";
    while (my $file = readdir($dh)) {
        if ($file =~ /(.*?\d+.bin)/) {
            push @source_files, $file;
        }
    }
    closedir $dh;
    return \@source_files;
}

sub DetermineFileInfo {
    my $source_files = (@_);
    foreach my $file (@$source_files) {
        print "$source_files\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The line `my $source_files = (@_);` assigns to a scalar `$source_files`, thus being in scalar context; it then uses the number of elements in the array, `1` here. Replace with `my ($source_files) = @_;`.  See practically the duplicate: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46232503/4653379) from a few days ago.

Comment: thank you, that fixed the problem; also, just putting parentheses around $source_files fixed the problem. i don't understand the purpose of shift

Comment: I am marking it as a duplicate since the error is exactly the same (even though the code is different), and the comment above with the same link solved it.  If there is a problem with this please let me know.

Comment: The `shift` removes an element from the front of the array, _and returns it_.  Then that can be assigned to a scalar.  By default it works on `@_` thus just `my $var = shift;`.  This is often used to first remove that element first so that the (remaining) `@_` can later be processed more easily.  For instance, in object-oriented code you'll often see `my $self = shift;` to get the object _and_ remove it from `@_`, so that `@_` stays with only the "real" arguments for method's operation.

Comment: I added a note on the use of `shift` for this purpose to the linked answer/duplicate

Answer (score 0):

use

```
my $source_files = shift;
```

instead of

```
my $source_files = (@_);
```

See the [documentation of shift](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) for more info.